# Javascript 1 === 1 is false

Tags: javascript, numbers, equals

I am fairly new to Javascript after discovering React JS, and am having an issue which I don't understand.

I have the following code, which console logs both variables as numbers with identical values. Yet it displays as false... Why?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
<Nav tabs>
    {
        navigation.map((page, i) => {
            ++i;

            var match = this.state.activeTab === { i };

            console.log(
                typeof(i) + " " + i,
                typeof(this.state.activeTab) + " " + this.state.activeTab,
                match
            );

            return (
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                        className={
                            classnames({
                                active: match,
                                'cursor-pointer': true
                            })
                        }
                        onClick={() => { this.toggleTab({ i }) }}
                    >
                        { page.name }
                    </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
            )
        })
    }
</Nav>
```

I get the following in my console log:

```
app.js:89525 number 1 number 1 false
app.js:89525 number 2 number 1 false
app.js:89525 number 3 number 1 false
app.js:89525 number 4 number 1 false
app.js:89525 number 5 number 1 false
app.js:89525 number 6 number 1 false
```

Surely the first log should display as true.

Comment: `{ i } !== i` but you never log `{ i }`

Comment: You are not doing `1 === 1` but `1 === {1}`. Remove the brackets

Comment: Looking at `this.state.activeTab === { i }` I can tell you that `{i}` is not a number, but an object with the following form: `{i: i}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what `this.state.activeTab` is, but it will ***never*** equal `{ i }`.

You're not comparing with a number, there, but with a new object containing a number.

That new object, `{ i }`, will *only* return `true` for the strict equality comparison (`===`) if you compare it with itself, which `activeTab` obviously isn't.

This will probably fix your code:

```
var match = this.state.activeTab === i;
```

<sup>(Assuming `activeTab` is a number)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. This was indeed the case. I'm not sure why I was typing out i as an ES6 obj. Such a silly mistake, so many new things to remember, and the code you gave worked perfectly. I will mark as accepted asap.

Answer (score 6):

`{ i }` is not `i`, it's (as of ES2015) an object with a property called `i`. So naturally if `this.state.activeTab` is `1`, `this.state.activeTab === { i }` is false, because a number cannot be `===` to an object.

You want

```
var match = this.state.activeTab === i;
 // No {} ---------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was completely right. Many many thanks :)